# Joomla error: 'Illegal variable _files or _env or _get or _post or _cookie or _server or _session or globals passed to script'

Tags: php, forms, joomla

I am getting this error in Joomla:

```
Illegal variable `_files` or `_env` or `_get` or `_post` or `_cookie`
or `_server` or `_session` or `globals` passed to script.
```

I didn't get much help googling.

Comment: You know all of those variables are uppercase, e.g. `$_POST`, right?

Comment: Some code and more details would be nice ...

Comment: Could you provide more info about what you are trying to do? What script did you run?

Comment: Wow. A new error message. Here I was thinking PHP held no more secrets :)

Comment: -1, unclear question. What is the actual error message? Can we see the code?

Comment: @halfer whats unclear in this question my friend. This is the actual error message. The code is just a form submitting some input fields. I am also not sure what should i post here. The form with fields? That would be of no interest to anybody. I thought someone who have already seen this before could post some hint.

Comment: See @BerryLangerak's answer for why it was unclear. The backticks made it look like these were alternative variants of the error... and you forgot to mention, critically, that this comes from Joomla.

Comment: @halfer fine with that. I was in joomla framework. I didnt knew it was something specific to joomla. Thanks

Comment: @halfer: now that it's been cleaned up, can you remove your downvote? This is a pretty useful question; I can imagine someone coming across this unhelpful error message and not having a clue where to begin, as was the case here

Comment: @BobbyJack - okay, done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll see this error if you try to specify a URL parameter whose name consists solely of digits, e.g.

```
http://www.example.com/?1234567=test
```

or if you try to use a joomla-reserved variable, e.g.

```
http://www.example.com/?_files=test
```

It's not a great error message. If you have access to a unix terminal, you can debug these kind of problems with some command-line tools, e.g.

```
$ find /var/www/html -exec grep -l 'Illegal variable' {} \;
/var/www/html/libraries/joomla/environment/request.php
```

This is a fictional joomla installation, assuming a fairly standard `DocumentRoot`. The result immediately confirms this is a Joomla error, and reports which file caused it. Extract from that file:

```
static $banned = array( '_files', '_env', '_get', '_post', '_cookie', '_server', '_session', 'globals' );

foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{   
    // PHP GLOBALS injection bug 
    $failed = in_array( strtolower( $key ), $banned );

    // PHP Zend_Hash_Del_Key_Or_Index bug 
    $failed |= is_numeric( $key );

    if ($failed) {
        jexit( 'Illegal variable <b>' . implode( '</b> or <b>', $banned ) . '</b> passed to script.' );
    }
    ...
}
```

Note that the error message is particularly misleading because, not only is in thrown in the case of a reserved variable name, but also if the parameter name is numeric.

Comment: @Hanny Thanks - I'll gladly take signups to the [Joomla Answers!](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla-answers) proposal in payment ;-)

Answer (score 4):

It's not an error PHP generates, it's an error that seems to belong to Joomla!. I found [this page](http://www.kareebu.com/kareebu-secure-manual/5-usage/11-illegal-variable) after 20 seconds of Googling for "Illegal variable".

Answer (score 0):

I had to fix this for joomla 1.5

Here is how I did it

Find the file /{your_joomla_folder}/libraries/joomla/environment/request.php

And make the error friendlier

```
function clean()
{
    JRequest::_cleanArray( $_FILES , false, 'FILES');
    JRequest::_cleanArray( $_ENV , false, 'ENV' );
    JRequest::_cleanArray( $_GET , false, 'GET' );
    JRequest::_cleanArray( $_POST , false, 'POST' );
    JRequest::_cleanArray( $_COOKIE , false, 'COOKIE' );
    JRequest::_cleanArray( $_SERVER , false, 'SERVER' );

    if (isset( $_SESSION )) {
        JRequest::_cleanArray( $_SESSION , false, 'SESSION' );
    }

    $REQUEST    = $_REQUEST;
    $GET        = $_GET;
    $POST       = $_POST;
    $COOKIE     = $_COOKIE;
    $FILES      = $_FILES;
    $ENV        = $_ENV;
    $SERVER     = $_SERVER;

    if (isset ( $_SESSION )) {
        $SESSION = $_SESSION;
    }

    foreach ($GLOBALS as $key => $value)
    {
        if ( $key != 'GLOBALS' ) {
            unset ( $GLOBALS [ $key ] );
        }
    }
    $_REQUEST   = $REQUEST;
    $_GET       = $GET;
    $_POST      = $POST;
    $_COOKIE    = $COOKIE;
    $_FILES     = $FILES;
    $_ENV       = $ENV;
    $_SERVER    = $SERVER;

    if (isset ( $SESSION )) {
        $_SESSION = $SESSION;
    }

    // Make sure the request hash is clean on file inclusion
    $GLOBALS['_JREQUEST'] = array();
}
function _cleanArray( &$array, $globalise=false, $type=null )
{
    static $banned = array( '_files', '_env', '_get', '_post', '_cookie', '_server', '_session', 'globals' );

    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        // PHP GLOBALS injection bug
        $failed = in_array( strtolower( $key ), $banned );
        $is_injection = false;
        if($failed){
            $is_injection = true;
        }

        // PHP Zend_Hash_Del_Key_Or_Index bug
        $failed |= is_numeric( $key );
        if ($failed) {
            if($type){
                $str = $type;
            }else{
                $str = implode( '</b> or <b>', $banned );
            }
            throw new Exception( 'Illegal variable <b>' . $str . '</b> passed to script.'.(($is_injection)?' (globals injection)': ' key "'.$key.'" is numeric in '.$str) );
            //jexit( 'Illegal variable <b>' . implode( '</b> or <b>', $banned ) . '</b> passed to script.' );
        }
        if ($globalise) {
            $GLOBALS[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

In my case an AJAX script was uploading files as

```
$_FILES = array(
    0=>array(
        [name] => 6767.bmp
    [type] => image/bmp
    [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpfbIzXU
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 12774
    ),
);
```

The 0 was causing problems, so because this was a minimal script I could simply transfer the info from `$_FILES` to somewhere else before joomla loaded

for example like this:

```
$files = array();
foreach($_FILES as $f){
    $files[] = $f;
}
$_FILES = array('files'=>$files);

... joomla launch code...
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(dirname(__FILE__).'/')));
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php';
require JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php';
```

Note that you can't use the variable `$files` after including `/includes/framework.php` as joomla will unhelpfully overwrite it with null

Answer (score -1):

**The only solution that worked** is to commnet out the following line in **request.php** file

Find the file /{your_joomla_folder}/libraries/joomla/environment/request.php

// $failed |= is_numeric( $key );