# PHP AJAX Joomla Authentication Script

Tags: php, authentication, post, namespaces, include

I have a PHP script like this:

```
<?php
include 'authorization_script.php';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
    //do something here
}
?>
```

The problem is **if** the "authorization_script.php" is passed a $_POST variable with only a numeric name, the script will crash.  Instead of fixing that issue, I just wish to make sure no $_POST variables are ever passed to the include script.

For it to work this "authorization_script" does not need any external variables, but since $_POST variables are global by default, they are passed to this script.  It was suggested in [one of my previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478974/php-include-require-without-passing-variables) that I can solve this problem with name spaces in PHP.

Could I change the namespace of the $_POST variables so that they are not passed to the include script?  If so, can someone help on how to do that?  Or is there a better way?

Thx

EDIT:  Instead of hacking my way out of this by renamig the $_POST variable, like a few of you have suggested I should fix the real problem.  This is an AJAX script inside a Joomla website.  When I call this ajax script I still want to authenticate the user, then grade credentials from the local database.  The way I found to authenticate users from the AJAX script is like this:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

/* Create the Application */
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');

/* Make sure we are logged in at all. */
if (JFactory::getUser()->id == 0)
    die("Access denied: login required.");
```

I think the error is being thrown form inside the joomla framework script (line 528 on [this script](http://api.joomla.org/__filesource/fsource_Joomla-Framework_Environment_joomlaenvironmentrequest.php.html)).

Any ideas of a better way to authenticate the users from experienced Joomla people?

Comment: Surely it would just be better to fix the actual problem? Why does your script crash? What error messages are you given?

Comment: Once you `foreach` the `$_POST` array into another array, why don't you just `unset($_POST);`?

Comment: @SourLemon The problem is part of the Joomla functions I am calling from "authorization_script.php".  For now I would rather not change that.

Comment: @wanovak -  That is not a bad idea. Thanks!

Comment: now after the update this is a totally new question, you should potentially handle it like that and open a new thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could I change the namespace of the $_POST variables so that they are
>   not passed to the include script?

No. Globals are global regardless of namespace.

> Or is there a better way?

Fix the include script. You should endeavour to make your code resilient to bad input -- *especially* code that performs authorization.

Comment: Yes I agree.  So although some good hacks were suggested that would probably work, I think I will try to fix the real problem. (see edit above)

Answer (score 3):

or if you dont want to fix your include script, you could do this awful hack:

```
<?php
// watch this ugly hack
$post_hack = $_POST;
unset($_POST);
include 'authorization_script.php';
$_POST = $post_hack;

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
    //do something here
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right this is very  ugly, but should fix it:

```
<?php
$aPost = $_POST;
unset($_POST);
include 'authorization_script.php';

foreach ($aPost as $key => $value){
    //do something here
}
?>
```