# PHP - Include files without inhereting variables?

Tags: php, variables, include, scope

Is it possible to include (or, for my uses, *run*) another PHP file from within a PHP script *without inheriting the variables set in the parent script*? I know this is mostly possible to do by [wrapping the include in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8479013/1382779), but that feels sloppy.

Is there a more elegant alternative?

Comment: The include will inherit whatever's in scope where included, so wrapping it in a function really is the solution.  The other solution is to limit the number of globals you're creating in the parent script.  If they ought not be exposed in various includes, then perhaps they _shouldn't be global to begin with_.

Comment: I don't actually have any set globals, so wrapping it in a function WILL solve the problem. I was just hoping there's a more specific function for it, or something. :)

Comment: Couldn't you just make them private variables in your class in the file you're including?

Comment: maybe you should stop using the "include oriented programming" and start learning OOP

Comment: Sometimes, for simple processing scripts, object-oriented programming slows the development process down. :) But you're right--in most cases, OOP would prevent this from being an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, at the time of this writing, it appears that wrapping what you want to include in a function or method is the only way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the include command into a include function.

```
    <?php
    //Führt die Cronjobs aus
    set_time_limit(30);

    /** Alle Dateien mit _cronjob am schluss sollen minütlich ausgeführt werden.*/
    $files = scandir(__DIR__ ."/cronjob");

    foreach($files as $file) {
        if($file == "." || $file == "..") continue;
        include_easy(__DIR__ ."/cronjob/". $file);
    }

    //Damit die variablen nicht überschrieben werden, wird das include über eine funktion gemacht.
    function include_easy($pfad) {
        include($pfad);
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work in PHP 8.1.9
Declared variables still get included.

Answer (score -2):

Make your variables in the file your including private variables.  That way they are included only in the file you want to inherit functions from.  This is a much cleaner way to approach the problem.

Comment: You can't make variables in the global scope private, doesn't make any sense.